# How to parse url params using queryString or any other method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question is simple. I know query-string npm do the job, but have the special case.
My query params look like this:

```
params={

foo:'bar',
data:[1,2,3],
data2:[4,5,6]
}
```

i need output something like `?foo=bar&data=1,2,3&data2=4,5,6`

not what done by [query-sting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string). [query-sting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) output it as

`?foo=bar&data=1 &data=2&data=3..........`

Comment: First have you tried anything? Second, do you need those spaces before and after `&`?

Comment: @Rajesh i try using query-string, with arrayIndex as optional parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem you are facing can be solved as follow:

```
const queryString = require('query-string')

const seacrh=queryString.stringify(params)
```

the above line produce `search=?foo=bar&data=1%0C2%0C3&data2=4%0C5%0C6`

In order to Remove illogical character, just decode the url using below lines of code

```
const search1=decodeURIComponent(seacrh);
```

The decodeURIComponent decode those illogical string.

Comment: What does a `seacrh` have to do with this? ^^

Comment: @BotNet, ya i know thats unnecessary. I can even write it as  ::::::::::::
const result =decodeURIComponent(queryString.stringify(params))

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what your after.

I've just used a array.join to get your data= into the correct format..

```js
var params={
  foo:'bar',
  data:[1,2,3],
  data2:[4,5,6]
};

//?foo=bar&data=1,2,3 & data2=4,5,6

console.log(
  `?foo=${params.foo}&data=${params.data.join(',')}&data2=${params.data2.join(',')}`);
```

Comment: i try this with sth like newdata=params.data.join(','). Then pass newdata as params.  eg params={foo:'bar',data:newdata}.

But the output is not as expected as it show sth like this. 
?foo='bar'&data=1%0C2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does the tick:

```js
var params = {
  foo:   'bar',
  data:  [1,2,3],
  data2: [4,5,6]
};

function toQuery (params) {
  var queryString = '';
  // Check that we've been suplied with an object.
  if (params.constructor !== Object) {
    return queryString;
  }
  // Iterate over parameters
  for (var param in params) {
    if (!params.hasOwnProperty(param)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (typeof params[param] === 'string' || typeof params[param] === 'number') {
      queryString += '&' + param + '=' + params[param];
    }
    if (params[param].constructor === Array && params[param].length) {
      queryString += '&' + param + '=' + params[param].join(',');
    }
  }
  // Change first '&' to '?'
  if (queryString.length) {
    queryString = '?' + queryString.substring(1);
  }
  // Return the query string, empty string if no usable parameters.
  return queryString;
}

console.log(toQuery(params));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to build your search:

```js
let params = {
  foo: 'bar',
  data: [1, 2, 3],
  data2: [4, 5, 6]
};

let queryString = Object.keys(params).map(
  key => `${key}=${params[key]}`
).join('&');

console.log(queryString)
```

- the string constructor will automatically comma-delimit the array
- this is very elementary and does not include any URI encoding, etc